# AutoComplete is not honoring value that is set through setState

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Autocomplete component from Material-UI version 5.11.6, and I am facing an issue when trying to set a value through setState. I have provided a sandbox example to illustrate the problem [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-raman-29t5js?file=/demo.tsx). Although I am able to set the value using setState, it is not being displayed in the Autocomplete component. To retrieve the object from the list of countries, I am using the Array.find method as shown below.

```
> <Autocomplete
id="country-select-demo"
sx={{ width: 300 }}
options={countries}
value={countries.find((item) => item.code === selectedValue)}
autoHighlight
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
renderOption={(props, option) => ()}`
> />
```

Country Barbados should have been displayed

Answer (score 0):

I changed the answer after the clarifications in the comments.

Into UseEffect you will get value from API call and set into selectedValue state,  the API response should has the same form of interface CountryType.

The value attribute must be set with selectedValue.

The onChange attribute must change and set value with newValue, like this:
onChange={(event, newValue) => setSelectedValue(newValue)}

Code below complete with changes:

```
export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const APIresponse = countries.find((item) => item.code === "BB")
      setSelectedValue(APIresponse);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  console.log(selectedValue);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      value={selectedValue}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => setSelectedValue(newValue)}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box
          component="li"
          sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
          {...props}
        >
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password" // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I want to set the AutoComplete value as "Barbados" on Mount of the component. But that's not happening even though I have set the state

Comment: If you want set "BB" on Mount you should set the state in this way:

`const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(countries.find((item) => item.code === "BB"));`

and add attribute **value** into component **Autocomplete** in this way:

`value={selectedValue}`

You can remove useEffect, after this change.

Comment: Actually, in a project I am working on, there is a call to an API that sets the state of the country. Therefore, in the above example, I have replicated the same issue using useEffect.

I have added setTimeout in the same example, I hope that gives more idea about what I am trying to do.

Comment: I am seeing this error message in the console. I hope this helps

`MUI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Autocomplete element for the lifetime of the component.
The nature of the state is determined during the first render. It's considered controlled if the value is not undefined.
    in Autocomplete (created by CountrySelect)
    in CountrySelect
`

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope now is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time! :) I was also able to solve this using another method. I simply had to add '|| null' to the value prop. [Here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36453#issuecomment-1459987235) is the link to the GitHub answer for the same question I had posted.